# How to add Plugin commands in the notepad++ right click menu?

Tags: notepad++

The following screen shows the menu of three commands that can work with the selected text. How to add additional Plugin commands in this menu?

[image: IMG:]

Answer (score 4):

In the Notepad++ installation folder, there is an xml file called `ContextMenu.xml`.

Usually it is located in

```
C:\program files\notepad++ or
C:\users\username\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++.
```

Here is where you add your custom plugin commands.

[image: notepad++ plugin context menu]

**Note:** You need to close Notepad++ and edit this xml file in some other editor, otherwise, it may not register your changes.

Comment: This works great! Thank you very much!

Comment: @HengLou, can you please accept it as an answer. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, I accept it as an answer

Comment: @HengLou There is a button you can press to officially mark the answer as an accepted answer, rather than just in a comment.